# Python processes and "could not allocate memory"

Tags: python

In my python code I use grab python lib and try to open 3 sites in ope python script

My current code:

```
from grab import Grab

...

g = Grab(interface=ip, headers=headers)
a = g.go('http://site1.com');

g = Grab(interface=ip, headers=headers)
b = g.go('http://site2.com');

g = Grab(interface=ip, headers=headers)
c = g.go('http://site3.com');
```

And this code working fine if I run even 10 python scripts

But I decide that better for me to open all connections in same time, (no wait when site "a" will be loaded before open site "b") And I tried to make processes:

```
pa = Process(target=m_a, args=(ip))

pb = Process(target=m_b, args=(ip))

pc = Process(target=m_c, args=(ip))

pa.start()
pb.start()
pc.start()
```

But when I try to run more than 5 python processes I see "could not allocate memory" message.

Why this code working in one python file, and "could not allocate memory" when I try to run it by processes for each site request?

Actuality I already use python process for running this python script, 
and my **name** != '**main**' . 
In first python (which run this script) I use this code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for f in [exit_error, exit_ok, return_value, raises, terminated]:
        print 'Starting process for', f.func_name
        j = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, name=f.func_name)
        jobs.append(j)
        j.start()
```

I use VPS OpenVZ 512

Error Report:

```
Process Process-18:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/root/_scripts/bf/check_current.py", line 140, in worker
    p.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Answer (score 0):

If the processes are running in parallel then you may indeed be running out of RAM.  Open Task Manager or its equivalent and check your total allocated memory as you run.

Comment: I've added full Traceback

Answer (score 0):

I found good command for set limit of memory using for python processes

```
ulimit -s 2000
```